# Precedence of chef attributes set in the chef-solo -j option?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

When setting attributes in the -j option of chef-solo the docs mention that they are set at the `default` level. According to the chef documentation on attributes, the ranking of attributes within the `default` level is in the following order (least to most priority):

1. Cookbook attribute file
2. Recipe attribute
3. Environment attribute
4. Role attribute

Where do attributes passed in via the chef-solo -j option fall in this ranking? Do they count as another cookbook attribute file, or would they be prioritized over everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options passed in via `-j` are set on the node during loading which ends up in the `normal` level.

Which docs did you see that claim it is default? I can make sure they get fixed.

Comment: I totally misinterpreted `normal` and `default` as being the same precedence level, which they clearly aren't. Thanks for making that clearer for me!

Comment: Such is the danger of using common words as very specific jargon :) You get weird sentences like "set attributes the `normal` level to override the default `default` value from the cookbook".